# Move one big table from MS SQL to no SQL DB

Tags: java, database, jdbc, nosql

We have a huge MS SQL DB which contains only one table. 
This table is very simple, we only do select, insert and delete. 
No join or update operations. 
even more, the insert/delete operations are from a single host in current architecture.

DB queries are very slow, even tough we add indexes, they don't help enough. 
We have unlimited number of small hosts we can use so, 
We are thinking of moving to distributed DB solution. 
But we want to keep the queries interface as similar to today as possible.

1. What is the best one for our need?
2. What will be the penalty for queries in the form of  == x
3. How can we do this transfer? minimal DB downtime is preferable of course, but we can manage (it saves BI information).
4. We are using JDBC, as we are accessing from a Java application, which ones work well iwth it?
5. From what I understand we need Document-oriented database, is that correct?

We have a lot of queries by fields, and we maintain keys for some of them. 
the more important ones are id, and a few date fields.
We don't only query by keys, we have queries for all the fields. 
We maintain a big table with a lot of columns. 
maybe HIVE is providing the solution we want, SQL queries but with distributed DB performance?
insert and delete performance is less important. long queries is what is disturbing us at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is seriously lacking in info. As David said, "please provide more information on the schema and usage". I would add to his questions:

 * How many columns are there on your single table?
 * How many records?
 * What is your read/write ratio?
 * What does a typical transaction look like?

I would add that "a single giant table" is a smell -- it makes me suspect that there are very many columns, perhaps many of them large and many of them null on many records, that is, the database is under-normalized. If this is right, a database redesign could be warranted.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options which may help you with your current RDBMS

- Can you shard the information? Do you have some natural key (user name, user id, time - month/day/hour etc.) by which you can separate the information into several tables? by itself this should give you huge benefits as the table size will be reduced significantly. I have employed this with success several times.
  Notice it means that it changes the way you access the DB - all CRUD operations must take the shard into account, and aggregate methods become more complex as they must run on multiple tables.
- Do you use some kind of replication? If you split your writes to one server and the writes to another server it should improve the performance.

To give better answer on which database suits you, please provide more information on the schema and usage - do you query by primary key only or by the fields as well? If you index the fields, then a document oriented database can suit you. Again, it depends on the total amount of information. Some databases (like MongoDB) are limited in the amount of information they can handle and recommend on sharding as well. All popular databases support Java, but not JDBC (as there are not relational...)

Regarding the migration - I would suggest a two phased approach:

1. Dump the current information and insert it (after conversion) to the new database
2. In your Java code add to your DAO a code that inserts the new data both to the RDBMS and the new database. It may be tricky to get a clean cut over, but you can set a time based threshold which may make it easier.

One final suggestion - have you looked at the new SQL databases like [VoltDB](http://voltdb.com/)?

**Edit**

Based on what you have written I would suggest either of the two:

- Document Oriented database, such as MongoDB or CouchDB, etc. which will allow you to index fields rather than just the primary key. In addition, Couchbase are doing [CouchConf-Israel](http://www.couchbase.com/couchconf-israel) in a few weeks, so you can go and ask for some help as well (sorry for the temporal nature of hits advice...)
- Column oriented database such as HBase, but here you will need to add tables for the field indices, as only the primary key of the table can be searched on.

Notice that Hive is a nice way to write Hadoop map-reduce methods, it does not guarantee any performance gains.

I also agree with Shai Berger - one big table does sound like a design smell. Can you break it?

Comment: Adding to this answer (and irrelevant to the question) how do you know the performance issues are in the database? have you done anything to check if its in the database or the JDBC driver? -> to give any better answer than David's we need more information, as he stated.

Comment: Thanks, sharding is another option we explore, but we are checking all areas. 
we know that it is the DB, we are checking it, and the problems are very slow DB response.

Comment: @Zamir To improve the answer, I need the answers - especially on this question:do you query by primary key only or by the fields as well? it will reflect on the databases you can use

Comment: added information about the queries character in the question

Comment: I would like to add support for understanding your current slowness better before deciding to change technologies. I would want confirmation that the query you are running is using an index efficiently (you should be able to profile your query to determine the  index usage and execution cost). From there you could look to see whether you are constrained by the hardware you are running on (no enough memory for example). Without understanding the root cause of the slowness there is a good chance you may run into the same issue on another platform.

Answer (score 0):

The table could have become fragmented.  You could try exporting and importing to a different server and run the same queries.  If they run faster, then its likely to be fragmented.

Comment: The table is huge, every some time we need to run maintenance on the keys, because they require refresh. that makes the DB even slower.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) ? it does wonderful things to RDBMS without changing your database infrastructure, i.e. depending one your queries patterns you should expect anything between x2-x10 performance improvement . Memcached clients are available to all programing languages and platforms